# how can i get the value in a map by key in angular js

Tags: angularjs, dictionary, filter

I am a newer in angular. I am trying to learn to use angular js. I have a problem here.
I have a map with name "nameMap" and its key->value following

```
    {
    1:su,
    2:mo,
    3:neptune
    }
```

what I want is when I get a key "key" such as "1", then display its mapped value "su" in page.

```
{{nameMap | key}}
```

I know I can do it if I achieve a filter myself. But I think this usage is so common that angular may do it with little code。
anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use `{{nameMap[key]}}`

Comment: I use Angular 2 and this didn't work. The answer from Mark worked for me.

Comment: That's doesn't work for types of Map<number, boolean> in Angular2+

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer would be to use `nameMap.get(key)` as of Angular 2.